# Getting Python.h: No such file or directory when compiling mod_wsgi on OSX with python3

Tags: mod-wsgi

I have updated the python code from Python2 to Python3. I had no issues compiling mod_wsgi with python2. But When I compile it with Python3, it's giving below error.

I tried to get rid of the mod_wsgi installed at OS level and tried pointing the ./configure script to different Python3 locations. But, nothing worked.

```
./configure -with-python=/usr/bin/python3
make

[user@xx-xx-xx-xx mod_wsgi-4.6.4]$ make
/usr/bin/apxs -c -I/usr/include/python3.7m -DNDEBUG -D_GNU_SOURCE  -Wc,-g -Wc,-O2  src/server/mod_wsgi.c src/server/wsgi_*.c -L/usr/lib64 -L/usr/lib64/python3.7/config-3.7m  -lpython3.7m -lcrypt -lpthread -ldl  -lutil -lm
/usr/lib64/apr-1/build/libtool --silent --mode=compile gcc -prefer-pic -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic  -DLINUX -D_REENTRANT -D_GNU_SOURCE -pthread -I/usr/include/httpd  -I/usr/include/apr-1   -I/usr/include/apr-1  -g -O2 -I/usr/include/python3.7m -DNDEBUG -D_GNU_SOURCE  -c -o src/server/mod_wsgi.lo src/server/mod_wsgi.c && touch src/server/mod_wsgi.slo
In file included from src/server/mod_wsgi.c:22:0:
src/server/wsgi_python.h:24:10: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
 #include <Python.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
apxs:Error: Command failed with rc=65536
```

Comment: you might be referring to a wrong path for python

Comment: How did you fix this issue? I've installed the necessary packages, and I can SEE that I have Python.h but it's still not finding it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution to this problem depends on your Linux distribution. You'll have to install the `dev` package for your Python version.

```
sudo apt-get install python3-dev
```

```
sudo yum install python3-devel
```

A more complete explanation on the missing Python header file can be found [here](https://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/installation-issues.html#missing-python-header-files)

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved it by installing python3-devel.
I seriously don't understand how these are related.